# How can I put my field values inside quotes (SQL)

Tags: sql

Code below puts quotes around any value in the field that contains a comma.

```
SELECT case when CHARINDEX(',',myField) > 0 
THEN '"'+ myField +'"' else myField END AS myField 
FROM myTable
```

The issue is that I want to select myField as Address but since I already have END AS I dont know how to go about. Hope my question is clear. Any help please.

Comment: Your statement `I want to select myField as Address` doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I nee to use SELECT AS statement with my case

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Your current query will return column with name 'myField'. Are you asking how to return it as 'Address'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've completely misunderstood you, you can just add `myField as address` to your query:

```
SELECT 
  case when CHARINDEX(',',myField) > 0 
  THEN '"'+ myField +'"' else myField END AS myField,
  myField as address 
FROM myTable
```

**UPDATE**

To get only one column named address:

```
SELECT 
  case when CHARINDEX(',',myField) > 0 
  THEN '"'+ myField +'"' else myField END AS address
FROM myTable
```

Comment: This will return two columns(Same columns twice rather)

Comment: So you want only one column named address? I've added a modified version to my answer.